# How to split data requests between two disks of different speed?

Tags: performance

I was recently asked this question in an interview-

Suppose I have two disks where speed of one disk is thrice the speed of other disk.So how should I divide my data on two disks so that my requests for data are optimally divided. He wanted to know how much data should I keep on fast disk and how much on slow disk so that my data requests are divided uniformly.

I had no proper answer and explanation at that time but I managed to say that I will keep 1/3rd on slow and 2/3rd on fast.

Can anyone tell me what should be the answer of this question?

Answer (score 0):

If one disk should receive three times more queries than another, then requests should be divided in the proportion 1:3, so 1/4 to the slow one and 3/4 to the fast one.

However the performance of the hard drive depends on the reading speed, writing speed and access time. These are different characteristics, so without knowing more about these disks it is difficult to say how one is three times faster than another.

Best would be to have a task queue and two threads, each picking tasks for its assigned disk as soon as it is free. However this is only possible if the design allows to direct the request to either disk.

Answer (score 0):

well...your answer strikes me as almost reasonable. If the speed of disk 1 is x and the speed of disk 2 is (1/3)x, you can do a little algebra and x + (1/3)x = 1 -> x(1 + 1/3) = 1
-> x (4/3) = 1 -> x = 3/4. Thus 3/4 on disk 1, 1/4 on disk 2.